# OpenCV shows white screen when using cv2.setWindowProperty("Image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using the following lines of code to set the image to fullscreen:

```
cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("Image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
```

The screen that opens is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf09i.jpg).

However, when I commented out `cv2.setWindowProperty("Image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)`, the image is shown. How do I fix this?

EDIT:
Full code:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("Image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

while cap.isOpened():
    success, image = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow("Image", image)

    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
      break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

EDIT: The version of opencv-python that I'm using is 4.7.0.68

EDIT: Code for reading image

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('path/to/image')
cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("Image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: The issue is not reproducible (in Windows 10). Are you capturing your screen or doing something unordinary? If the camera faces the screen it may happen.

Comment: Apologies, I should mention, I'm using a Macbook M1. No, I'm using the laptop webcam so it should just be capturing my face

Comment: It's probably a bug in OpenCV that is related to Macbook M1. I assume it's not happening when not using `cv2.setWindowProperty`. Are you also getting a white screen when reading an image from a file?

Comment: Yep, just tried

Comment: [edit] your question and update the [mcve] to one that just loads an image, like you said you tried. The smaller, the better (especially if it doesn't need a camera). Then try downgrading to some older versions of OpenCV (binary search approach is useful), and see if it still happens in all of them, or if it's something recent. Then [file an issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues) on OpenCV's github, providing all the details you've collected.  (Note: do some quick search there before posting to see if it wasn't reported recently)

Comment: Hi @DanMašek, thanks, I downgraded opencv-python to 4.4.0.46 and now it works